# Print Style in ASP.NET in IE8

Tags: asp.net, css, printing

I am trying to link a stylesheet to a masterpage in SharePoint with asp.net. It is a print-only stylesheet. The problem im having is that @media print does not work in IE8.
Can i add a stylesheet in asp.net that only applies to print media?

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CssRegistrationCommon"  Name="<% $SPUrl:/Style Library/CSS/common.css %>" After="corev4.css" runat="server"/>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also specify the media on the link for the stylesheet.

media="print"

make sure you main stylesheet points to something like screen/projector so they don't overlap

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/CSS/mystyles.css") %>" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/CSS/print.css") %>" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

Comment: How would you do that in ASP.NET?